# unable to load images and styles in child blade layout extending master blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am using `Laravel 5` and everything is working fine except i am unable to extend master blade template below is my hierarchy

`resource/views/master.blade.php
resource/views/welcome.blade.php
resource/views/pages/about.blade.php`

when i `extend` master blade in `welcome.blade.php` everything works fine, images load perfectly, styles load perfectly, but when i `extend` master blade in `pages/about.blade.php` images are not loading and styles also not loading. i am extending using `@extends('master')` . What can be the issue ? my head starded spinning because i am carefully going through `documentations & Laracasts video tutorials`. Please Help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So how are you writing it in the extended files? i do:

```
 @extends('main')
 @section('content')
 html stuff and blade stuff
 @stop
```

Then in the master file, you have to

```
yield('content')
```

solution was a missing "/" in the link, so the link should start with a leading "/", as in src="/link/to/img.png"

Comment: What is the url to the pages/about.blade.php?

Comment: How do you include the css file?

like:
<pre>
<link href="/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</pre>

Comment: yes i am adding css like u said and the images aswell

Comment: can you copy-paste a line with a css og image link that doesn't load?

Comment: `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
`

Comment: `<img src="img/logo.jpg" class="wow pulse" data-wow-iteration="3" data-wow-duration="0.15s">`

Comment: add a leading "/" before the link, like this:
<img src="/img/logo.jpg" class="wow pulse" data-wow-iteration="3" data-wow-duration="0.15s">

Comment: Ooops :-) now i can see the logo on about blade... phew, Thanks man you really saved my time. going to accept your answer... also edit your answer and add your suggestions in the main answer so the goof like me can take help from it :-) once again, thank your very much for your time

Comment: :-( i need 15 reputation to mark as accpted ... right now i am on 14, let's wait for me to get 1 more point and i'll definitly accept your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are added

```
 @yield
 @section
 @parent
 @stop
```

where is need and with correct parameters ?

Comment: yes i added @yield in master blade to display content... should i remove it and use something else ?

Answer (score 0):

Please mention in a little more detail with your sample code snippets.
As far as I can figure out, try using like this-

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

Please let me know further if the problem is resolved or not resolved with this.

Comment: dear Anshu, I have already got my workaround from Renee answer below, it's exactly the same as yours but thank you very much for your time and support. Really appreciate it :-)

Comment: It should be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= asset('css/style.css') ?>">`